# Remove current model instance from AR:Relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, instance

I am creating an instance method on a model which returns instances of the same model. How can I ensure that the instance of the model that the method is being called upon is not part of the output?

My code is like this at the moment:

```
  def other_versions(include_current = true)
    if include_current
      Coaster.where(order_ridden: order_ridden)
    else
      @coaster.other_version_count // Need this to exclude the current instance.
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood, but would this help?

```
def other_versions(include_current = true)
  query = Coaster.where(order_ridden: order_ridden)
  query = query.where("id != ?", id) unless include_current
  query
end
```